# Intuition for L'Hopital's rule in the $\infty/\infty$ case?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have been struggling to get the intuition for L'Hopital's rule in its $\infty/\infty$ form. I have been thinking about this for a while now, and I looked at various posts on math stack exchange. However, the most popular explanations I have seen only deal with the $0/0$ case, and many answers just mention something like "the $\infty/\infty$ case is analogous and can be generalized without difficulty". Another type of popular explanation says that

> The intuition is that although both numerator and denominator tend to zero or infinity, what eventually matters is their respective rate of change. They do not approach zero or infinity at the same rate and thus the one with the highest rate of change dominates the other.

I have also seen rigorous proof of the result from baby Rudin (Theorem 5.13), and from various other sources including (arguably) Wikipedia. In most of these proofs of the $\infty/\infty$ case, we just manipulate $$\frac{f(x) - g(y)}{g(x) - g(y)}$$ by dividing the numerator and denominator by $g(x)$, so we have $$\frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - \frac{g(y)}{g(x)}}{1 - \frac{g(y)}{g(x)}}.$$ Then an argument like "keeping $y$ fixed, as $x \to a$, $g(x) \to \infty$ and so $\frac{g(y)}{f(x)}$ and $\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}$ vanish" is used to deduce the result.
Although I am convinced of the validity of these proofs, I hardly gain any insights from these proofs. To me, these proofs just magically manipulated the numbers and get the result, and I didn't learn the intuitions behind the theorem. 
Can someone kindly provide me with an intuition of the $\infty/\infty$ case? Geometric interpretation would be the best and much appreciated! My thanks in advance?

Comment: Can you understand the $0/0$ case?

Comment: Hi Tab1e, thank you for your comment, I believe I understand the $0/0$ case somewhat intuitively. We know that $f(x_0) \approx f(x) + f'(\zeta)(x_0 - x)$ and $g(x_0) \approx g(x) + g'(\zeta)(x_0 - x)$ for some $\zeta \in (x, x_0)$. If two functions $f$ and $g$ start with $0$ at $x$, then it seems that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ would vanish and leaving us with $f(x_0) = f'(x)(x_0 - x)$ and $g(x_0) = g'(x)(x_0 - x)$. So $f(x_0)/g(x_0)$ should approximately be $f'(x)/g'(x)$ for $x_0$ close enough to $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Interpret this physically, with functions being distance traveled from some starting point, the variable being time, and derivatives being velocity.

Two trains travel on parallel tracks.  If one of the trains is traveling roughly twice as fast as the other ($f'/g' \to 2$), don't you expect in the long run that the faster train, over a long time interval, will travel rough twice as far ($f/g \to 2$)?

Comment: Hello KCd, thank you for your explanation, but isn't the condition that $\lim_{x \to a} f'(x)/g'(x)$ just saying that at some particular moment $a$, one train is travelling at approximately twice as fast as another one? Also, what confuses me even more is that they have already travelled a lot of distance, so somehow it seems to me that at this particular moment their velocity wouldn't make that much of the difference.

Comment: I had in mind the limit as $t \to \infty$ (long-term effects), not anything else.

Comment: Hi KCd, thank you for the clarification. I agree that if two trains keep their velocity at a ratio of approximately 2 over long-term, then the ratio of distance should be approximately 2. However, what if the ratio of velocity is instant at a moment instead of over a long period of time? I think the "instant" case is what L'Hopital's rule is saying.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule has *many* variations.  You are interested in limits at a finite point. I wrote about limits as $t \to \infty$. It's not accurate to say L'Hospital's rule covers only one case and not the other.  Consider making a change of variables that brings a finite point out to $\infty$, e.g., if you want to look at $f(t)/g(t)$ as $t \to 2^+$, set $x = 1/(t-2)$, so $x \to \infty$ and $f(t)/g(t) = f(2 + 1/x)/g(2 + 1/x)$. If $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ were both tending to $\infty$ as $t \to 2^+$ then $f(2+1/x)$ and $g(2 + 1/x)$ both tend to $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: The $x$-derivative ratio for $f(2 + 1/x)/g(2+1/x)$ is $f'(2 + 1/x)/g'(2 + 1/x)$ since the $-1/x^2$ factor from the chain rule in the numerator and denominator cancels out. Does this change of variables help you see that if you accept the intuition for behavior at $\infty$ then it follows for limits as $t \to 2^+$?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I am confused by the baby Rudin version. Can I interpret this change of variable operation as essentially somehow making the moment $t \to 2^+$ "infinitely long"? And then since during this "infinitely long period" the velocity ratio is approximately constant $2$, so "at the end of infinity" their distance should approximately be $2$ as well? However, how are $f$ and $g$ $\to \infty$ used in this interpretation? It seems that I can generalize this change of variable argument to any arbitrary $t$ without considering $\lim f(t)$ and $\lim g(t)$?

Comment: Math doesn't know what "infinitely long" means for limits. It is just a change of variables. A limit as $t \to 2^+$ is the same as a limit as $x \to \infty$ when $t = 2 + 1/x$, no more and no less. When you write about "at the end of infinity" it sounds like the way people spoke 350 years ago.